# About Facebook App review with new policy

Tags: facebook

I notice that Facebook app policy is going to be changed on April 30th, 2015. My app is under the policy due to the app uses Facebook SDK 1.x and it posts contents using `publish_actions` permission.

If the app is not get through Facebook's app review with old SDK before due date, is `publish_actions` permission blocked automatically?

And, if the app doesn't pass the review although it uses new 2.x SDK, is `publish_actions` permission blocked too?

Comment: I'm not a player in this area, Sir, but in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/migrate), they said that it's not required, but encouraged. Since after April 2015, there will be no support for the sdk v1.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 Thanks. But, I didn't find any exact answer I'm looking for on link you suggest. I wonder if posting action will be blocked or not after April 2015.

Comment: sorry, but indeed not supported is a little bit vague here. If you read "Versioning" section: `Multiple versions of the API will be in service at the same time.`, that's why in the beginning I supposed sdk v1 would also be in service. But when I read `"will only be available until April 30th 2015"`, perhaps it wouldn't be in service anymore.
In the end, for your app's safety and up-to-date functions, you shall just migrate without wondering whether things would be blocked or not.

Comment: Recommendation: Always update to latest version of SDK (I know there are a lot of changes to make)